# UIModalTransitionStyle is incompatible

Tags: iphone

**property type UIModalTransitionStyle is incompatible with type UIModalTransitionStyle inherited from UIViewController**

Getting the above warning message after setting the property of UIModalTransitionStyle

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIModalTransitionStyle *modalTransitionStyle;
@synthesize modalTransitionStyle;
```

This is simple property declaration

Have any ideas why getting this message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way you are supposed to use `UIModalTransitionStyle`.

Take a look at this property of `UIViewController` here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Your code should be something like:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MyClass alloc] init];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

According to UIViewController class reference UIModalTransitionStyle can be:

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```